# How can I create a table div with auto width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create DIV HEAD as a table, but when I add another head it shows down and not to the right.

In other words, I want the table to be six columns wide, but it is only 3, and the rows start to stack.

Here is a live demo:

```css
    .rTable {    
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 10px; 
    } 
    
    .rTableHeading, .rTableBody, .rTableFoot, .rTableRow{ 
     clear: both; 
    } 
    
    .rTableHead, .rTableFoot{    
      background-color: #DDD;    
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .rTableCell, .rTableHead {     
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      float: left; 
      height: 17px; 
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 3px 1.8%; 
      width: 28%;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="rTable"> 
      <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 1</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 2</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 3</div>  
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 4</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 5</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 6</div> 
      </div> 
  
      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.6</div>  
      </div> 
  
      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.6</div>  
      </div> 

      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.6</div>  
      </div>  

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use `width: calc(100% / 6);` (make one column one 6th of the parent width) and `box-sizing: border-box;` (ignore padding for element width):

```css
.rTable {    
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 10px; 
    } 
    
    .rTableHeading, .rTableBody, .rTableFoot, .rTableRow{ 
     clear: both; 
    } 
    
    .rTableHead, .rTableFoot{    
      background-color: #DDD;    
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .rTableCell, .rTableHead {     
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      float: left; 
      height: 17px; 
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 3px 1.8%; 
      width: calc(100% / 6); 
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div class="rTable"> 
      <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 1</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 2</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 3</div>  
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 4</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 5</div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">HEAD 6</div> 
      </div> 
  
      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 1.6</div>  
      </div> 
  
      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 2.6</div>  
      </div> 

      <div class="rTableRow" style="page-break-before:always;">
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.1</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.2</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.3</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.4</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.5</div>  
        <div class="rTableCell">row 3.6</div>  
      </div>  

    </div>
```

Comment: If I add more than 6 and with mor words HEAD for example: instead of HEAD1 show NAME OF EMPLOYEE - NAME OF WIFE ...that will be a problem...is there any other way to may this in a dynamic way?

Comment: You have two options for longer head titles: 1. give the table more width or 2. break long titles into multiple lines...

Answer (score 2):

```
.rTableCell, .rTableHead {     
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left; 
  height: 17px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%; 
  width: calc(100% / 6); 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: It will work because of `box-sizing: border-box;` ;)

Comment: For sure! That's a different story ;) I updated my snippet with that idea.

Comment: Someone post about Using_CSS_flexible_boxes is that a correct way too?

Answer (score 1):

Your `rTableCell` and `rTableHead` are set to `width: 28%;` in your CSS. Six side-by-side is 168%.

If you want to fit six accross, you'll need to do something more like `16%`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your cells are 28% wide. That's far more than 100% which is the maximum. 10% works for example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6qsg5wa/1/)

Better than absolute percentages would be calculated ones like `calc(100% / 6)`.

May I ask why you create tables by `div`s and not `<table>`? Would be much easier.